# How to put Code-Behind Class of UserControl.ascx in another Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, code-behind, ascx

I have one UserControl.ascx and want this ascx use (reference) the code-behind that is in **another library (project)**. So in the `@control` directive i do the following

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="..\CodeBehinds\ucBehind1.cs" %>
```

but when a run the page i see the error

```
Parser Error Message: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.
```

Is there a way to achieve it?

[GitHub example Project](https://github.com/Ewerton/UserControlsCodeBehind)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, remove the inherits from UserControl1.ascx

In usercontrol1.ascx.cs, uncomment all your code.

Change

```
public partial class UserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

To

```
public partial class UserControl1 : otherClassInAnotherProject
```

otherClassInAnotherProject should in the end inherit from System.Web.UI.UserControl

Comment: if i do this, i will just make my UserControl inherit from `UcBehind`. This is not the requirement.

Comment: I changed my example, instead of UcBehind, Usercontrol would inherit from this other class that is in another project.  As long as you have your reference to this other project is should work.

Comment: but this still being just an heritance, i need to `move` the code-behind file to another project.

Comment: I'm assuming that a reference to that other project is out of the question as well?